# what should CRUD (Insert and Update) functions return ?

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, crud

I could return nothing .. I could return true/false to show if there are any problems.. I could return an int being the primary key of what was inserted or updated.. I could create a custom object to return more information.. perhaps hold a collection of all the validation errors or something that may have occurred..

So it is not something I am stuck with but I just seem to randomly pick different way so would like to hear a best practice for these common functions..

I am using C#/Entities/Repository pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really a matter of personal preference. You might want to distinguish between commands and queries.

So creates, updates and deletes would be commands and I would expect them to return void.

Reads would be queries and would return IQueryable.

However, if you routinely want to use an inserted object directly after inserting it you may want to return the object as a result of the insert.

Comment: If I return void then how do I handle something going wrong on the update.. or if it is a group of updates then the specific row..  I feel like it does not hurt anything to return too much info but I also don't want to return something for no reason..

Comment: If something goes wrong on the update you should be throwing an exception.

Comment: But if I can handle it in code I could just make a note of the error and pass it back to the caller as well... but.. I guess what you are saying is that is what exceptions are for.. no need to create a return type to hold this info.. right?

Comment: Right. An update statement should not go wrong. If it does then an exception is correct and appropriate.

Comment: I have a coworker who wants to return a list of all of the items that pertain to a particular piece of data after any one of those items is updated. This seems like a horrible idea to me because it increases the data payload enormously for no reason that I can discern. Is there a method to his madness?

Answer (score 2):

imho, this is an open question. As a fan of fluent API, I return, in casae of success, the inserted, updated object.

Otherwise (if something wrong or unexpected happens), I throw.

Comment: In what way would you possibly use the inserted/updated object that is returned back to the caller ? Im not familiar with fluent API so maybe I am missing sometihng

Comment: I thought throwing exceptions was used only when the code does not know what to do?.. I mean something extreme happening that cannot be handled...  So you are saying throwing excetinos can be used more casually? as in to return some information throw the excetion.. rather than a custom object?

Comment: the only example I have in mind, right now, is the case of a database generated id: `Int32 newId = SomeInsert(someParams).Id;`. Why not returning it directly well. I may need the inserted updated as a reference for a navigation property of another object...

Comment: Ok.. that sounds more advanced that what I am doing.. I am just inserting.. and needing a way to verify it worked.. then forgot about it.. .So the question is now just.. How do I relay to the caller about errors occurred.. custom objects as the return type OR use exceptions as the method to pass any information about problems to the caller

Comment: In java (hibernate) it is common practice to return the object that you inserted/updated so it can be merged with the session again. That way the data is synchronized between the DB & the session

Comment: @punkouter, I don't have The definitive answer, but using exception is not a heresy.

Comment: ok.. I guess ill start using exceptions more often and get rid of the idea of having a custom object hold my errors.

Comment: Another reason to return the object you just Created/Updated is to return information about it that isn't available to the client e.g. if you have auto-generated 'LastModifedBy' and 'LastModifiedAt' value that the client needs to know.